# How can I check if the sub-sublist of a list contains one item and if so delete it?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks something like this.

```
mylist = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']], [['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']], [['destination', 'graph']]]
```

I would like to delete the sublist `[['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']]` since it has one elements only(all one elements in that sublist).

Once this is deleted, I have an index_list, that looks like this:

```
index_list = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [1, 2, 3]], [5, [0]]]
```

The relation of `mylist` and `index_list`

```
[0, [1, 2]]
```

```
[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']]
```

where 1 relates to

```
['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']
```

and 2 relates to

```
['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']
```

Since `['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']` is deleted, I would like to update `[4, [1, 2, 3]]` to `[4, []]`

INPUT

```
index_list = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [1, 2, 3]], [5, [0]]]
```

```
mylist = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']],[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']], [['destination', 'graph']]]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
index_list = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, [0]]]
```

```
mylist = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']],[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [], [['destination', 'graph']]]
```

Comment: You wan to delete `[['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']]` based on which condition? All the sublists contain only one item or all the sub-lists contain same item or both condition?

Comment: I didn't get the relation of `mylist` and `index_list`. How did you get `[2, [0, 2]]`?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. But I have a hunch, it can be done in a much simpler manner!!

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev All the sublists contain only one item.

Comment: @mrzrm `[2, [0, 2]]` would related to `[['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']]`, where `0` relates to `['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph']` and `2` to `['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']`

Comment: Why choosing 0 and 2

Comment: When you finish writing whatever you are writing now, I suggest posting your full code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I'm pretty sure there is a better way to achieve what you want. Those 3-leveled nested lists of indices just don't look right.

Comment: @SmartManoj he asked me how the relation of `[2, [0, 2]]` works, but this won't be deleted.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex why not `[2, [0, 1]]`?

Comment: @mrzrm because the sub-sublist has more than 1 item, so it doesn't need to be deleted.

Comment: I would suggest to make one structure if the two lists are related. A dictionary seems like a good choice: `{k[0]:{sk:sv for sk,sv in zip(k[1],v)} for k,v in zip(index_list,mylist)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reversed to avoid IndexError

```
for k,i in enumerate(mylist):
    for k2,j in reversed(list(enumerate(i))):
        if len(j)==1:
            del mylist[k][k2]
            del index_list[k][1][k2]
```

---

```
# Expected
index_list1 = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, [0]]]
mylist1 = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']],[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [], [['destination', 'graph']]]
# Original
index_list = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [1, 2, 3]], [5, [0]]]
mylist = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']],[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [['modify'], ['modify2'], ['modify3']], [['destination', 'graph']]]

for k,i in enumerate(mylist):
    for k2,j in reversed(list(enumerate(i))):
        if len(j)==1:
            del mylist[k][k2]
            del index_list[k][1][k2]

assert (index_list==index_list1)            
assert (mylist==mylist1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
mylist = [[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']], [['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']], [['destination', 'graph']]]
index_list = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [1, 2, 3]], [5, [0]]]
todelete = [['modify'], ['modify'], ['modify']]
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    if v == todelete:
        mylist[i] = []
        index_list[i][-1] = []

print(mylist)
print("---")
print(index_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'],
  ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']],
 [['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']],
 [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'],
  ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']],
 [['return', 'modify']],
 [],
 [['destination', 'graph']]]
---
[[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, [0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way :

```
for (i,j),(k,l) in zip(enumerate(mylist), enumerate(index_list)):
    new_sub_itm = [m for m in j if len(m)!=1]
    if not new_sub_itm:
        index_list[k][1] = []
        mylist[i] = []
```

As your `mylist` and `index_list` are of same length, you can enumerate them both and then zip along, then check whether the sub-lists contain only one item or not. If they contain only one item in each sub-list, `new_sub_itm` would be a vacant list `[]`. You can delete that item from `mylist` with index as well as change the second item in the `index_list`.

**Output** :

```
# index_list
[[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, [0]]]
# mylist
[[['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination'], ['add', 'all', 'edge', 'source', 'destination']], [['add', 'vertex', 'all', 'source', 'destination']], [['destination', 'add', 'source', 'graph'], ['destination', 'add', 'edge', 'source']], [['return', 'modify']], [['destination', 'graph']]]
```

Comment: It should delete only if all the sublists have 1 items ;Also `del mylist[i]` should be `mylist[i]=[]` ;